# How can I remove duplicate and erroneous entries from System Profiler's list of "Installations"?

Tags: macos, system-profiler

System Profiler ➞ Software ➞ Installations contains a list of every package you've installed on your machine.

For various reasons, there is some software I've had to reinstall more than once, such as Zoom. This software appears on the list of Installations multiple times.

[image: Installations Screenshot]

There is also some software that I am quite confident has been fully removed from my machine, but which nonetheless still appears in this list.

These entries aren't harming me or anyone else, so I really *should* just leave them be. Unfortunately, their presence is inexplicably *bothering me*!

How is this list generated, and can it be cleaned up?

Comment: Possibly install receipts? (/private/var/db/receipts)

Comment: @1110101001 I don't think that's it because it doesn't match the list. For instance, as part of uninstalling XQuartz I purposefully ran `pkgutil --forget` to complete the cleanup, and so unsurprisingly there aren't any receipts for XQuartz. But as you can see in the screenshot, XQuartz is still in System Profiler, multiple times in fact.

Comment: /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist ?

Comment: Reference: the system profiler sections are contributed by individual bundles, and the bundle for install history is at "/System/Library/SystemProfiler/SPInstallHistoryReporter.spreporter". Disassembling that  shows it calls into "[PKInstallHistory defaultHistory]"

Comment: And of course the wonderful osx internals book mentions this: http://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1AppA.html